How to define a .meta:n key preserving hashes?
I have a command that sets some keys, does stuff with the keys, and defines a new "meta" style with those keys to be called later with inherit-style=<style name>. This works fine using the .meta:n handler except when the key value contains macro parameters #1, #2, etc.
Here's an example.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    % <code with key values>
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
      { inherit-style / #1 .meta:n = { #2 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2}
\NewStyle{mysty2}{inherit-style=mysty}

\begin{document}
\end{document}

This errors with
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \key code > mymodule/inherit-style/
mysty.

My current workaround is to precompile the keys in a tl and define inherit-style/<style> with that.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_precompile:nnN { nnc }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    % <code with key values>
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl }
    \keys_precompile:nnc { mymodule } { #2 }
      { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl }
    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
      { inherit-style / #1 .code:n = \tl_use:c { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2}
\NewStyle{mysty2}{inherit-style=mysty}

\begin{document}
\end{document}

However, my use case requires the use of \l_keys_key_str in the key definitions, which gives the "wrong" value with my workaround. The following example shows the issue. It interprets the current key to be inherit-style rather than anotherkey in the second \NewStyle.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_precompile:nnN { nnc }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2,
    anotherkey .code:n = \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_keys_key_str,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
    % <code with key values>
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl }
    \keys_precompile:nnc { mymodule } { #2 }
      { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl }
    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
      { inherit-style / #1 .code:n = \tl_use:c { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2,anotherkey}
\NewStyle{mysty2}{inherit-style=mysty}

\begin{document}
\end{document}

Is there any way to define a .meta:n key that can handle macro parameters?
Edit
I cannot just double hashes as suggested because the command needs to use the command defined with somekey. Here's a failing example with doubled hashes.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    \mymodule_command:nn{A}{B}
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
%    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
%      { inherit-style / #1 .meta:n = { #2 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2} % errors if inherit-style def uncommented
\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub ##1 abc ##2} % errors

\end{document}


There is a reason for this, because .meta:n keys accept a value and you can use that value as part of the meta replacement. So \keys_define:nn {set} { foo .meta:n = { bar = {#1} } } ensures that \keys_set:nn { foo = baz } sets bar = {baz}.
However, if your .meta:n should never accept a value what you can do is manually change # to ## via code. Note that this is no easy task, you have two possible approaches: Use l3regex (slow) or a token-by-token parser (faster, but might have side effects depending on the used parser).
The following implements the idea with a token-by-token parser using the etl package (disclaimer: I'm the author of etl).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    % <code with key values>
    \mymodule_command:nn {A} {B}
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \keys_define:ne { mymodule }
      {
         inherit-style / #1 .meta:n =
          { \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNn {#2} ## {####} }
        ,inherit-style / #1 .value_forbidden:n = true
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \test { mm } { \mymodule_command:nn {#1} {#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand \SetStyle { m }
  { \keys_set:nn { mymodule } {inherit-style = {#1}} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2}

\NewStyle{mysty2}{inherit-style=mysty}

\SetStyle{mysty2}
\test{A}{B}
\end{document}


This defines an alternative variant .meta:n based on token lists:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
     inherit-style .code:n =
      \tl_if_exist:cTF { l_mymodule_metakeys_ #1 _tl }
        { \keys_set:nv { mymodule } { l_mymodule_metakeys_ #1 _tl } }
        { \msg_error:nnn { mymodule } { unknown-style } {#1} }
    ,somekey .cs_set:Np = \mymodule_command:nn #1#2
    ,anotherkey .code:n = \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_keys_key_str
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
    % <code with key values>
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_mymodule_metakeys_#1_tl } {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub #1 abc #2,anotherkey}
\NewStyle{mysty2}{inherit-style=mysty}

\begin{document}
\end{document}


Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Assuming one could define their own key handler (which I know is not supported), would it be possible to define a meta key that does not take arguments and for which hashes don't need to be doubled?

@mbert yes, that's easily possible, you could patch something together with .code:n. I'll add something.

Ah I should have been able to come up with your second example. Is it right that \tl_set:Nn is basically the \edef+\unexpanded trick to prevent hash doubling? In any case, thanks for the excellent answer

@mbert yes, exactly that is what \tl_set:Nn does.

As with any nested definition ## denotes # so
\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub ##1 abc ##2}

runs without error.

After your update you need to make sure all keys using the argument cycle through the same number of definitions so eat up the same number of ## replacements.  I added a \show for debugging
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    somekey .code = \def\foo##1##2{\cs_set:Npn\mymodule_command:nn ##1##2{#1}}\foo{##1}{##2}\show\mymodule_command:nn,
    inherit-style .choice:,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewStyle } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #2 }
    \mymodule_command:nn{A}{B}
    \group_end:
    % Store #2 in meta key
    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
      { inherit-style / #1 .meta:n = { #2 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub ##1 abc ##2} % errors

\end{document}

gives
> \mymodule_command:nn=\long macro:
#1#2->blub #1 abc #2.

Note it's easier to have extra definitions to make both keys use ##1 thean to avoid having to double and make both use #1

Yes but then \mymodule_command:nn is not usable when \NewStyle{mysty}{somekey=blub ##1 abc ##2} is called because it's expecting single hashes

@mbert I would have tested more but your example didn't test any calls:-), if you add a test I'll update or delete, thanks

@mbert did you try? It should work as the ## are turned into single # in the replacement text of the .meta:n key.

I'll update question

@Skillmon I would have expected it to work as well, but there is no test file so who knows

I just added a simple test file and it does work for me.

I've updated the question with a more concrete example

@mbert answer updated
